# An elementary combinatorics problem.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Assume $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Z$ are pairwise coprime and also satisfy $2^{3n}<a,b,c,d<2^{3n+1}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$.

Is it true that each value of $aw+bx+cy+dz$ is distinct when $w,x,y,z\in\Bbb Z$ is varied in $0<w,x,y,z<2^{n-1}$ holds?

Comment: This cannot be true, for size reasons already: There are approx. $\left(2^n\right)^4 = 2^{4n}$ values possible for the quadruple $(w,x,y,z)$, but $aw+bx+cy+dz$ has to range between $0$ and $4\cdot 2^n 2^{n+1} = 2^{2n+3}$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg you are correct. Is it ok I modify my problem a bit?